# OBS display draw transparent background

Tags: c++, c, opengl, directx, obs

I want to draw a transparent window which render by obs-display, when i set the aplha channel, it not working when render.

obs fill a default background color(0x4C4C4C), obs's code set the alpha to 1.0 ,I try to set the others value like 0.5f, but it is not working.

```c
// libobs/obs-display.c
static inline void render_display_begin(struct obs_display *display,
        uint32_t cx, uint32_t cy, bool size_changed)
{
    struct vec4 clear_color;

    gs_load_swapchain(display->swap);

    if (size_changed)
        gs_resize(cx, cy);

    gs_begin_scene();

    // obs fill a default background color(0x4C4C4C)
    vec4_from_rgba(&clear_color, display->background_color);

    // obs's code set the alpha to 1.0 here
    // I try to set the others value like 0.5f, but it is not working
    clear_color.w = 1.0f; 

    gs_clear(GS_CLEAR_COLOR | GS_CLEAR_DEPTH | GS_CLEAR_STENCIL,
            &clear_color, 1.0f, 0);

    gs_enable_depth_test(false);
    /* gs_enable_blending(false); */
    gs_set_cull_mode(GS_NEITHER);

    gs_ortho(0.0f, (float)cx, 0.0f, (float)cy, -100.0f, 100.0f);
    gs_set_viewport(0, 0, cx, cy);
}

void gs_clear(uint32_t clear_flags, const struct vec4 *color, 
        float depth, uint8_t stencil)
{
    GLbitfield gl_flags = 0;

    if (clear_flags & GS_CLEAR_COLOR) {
        glClearColor(color->x, color->y, color->z, color->w);
        gl_flags |= GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
    }

    if (clear_flags & GS_CLEAR_DEPTH) {
        glClearDepth(depth);
        gl_flags |= GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
    }

    if (clear_flags & GS_CLEAR_STENCIL) {
        glClearStencil(stencil);
        gl_flags |= GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT;
    }

    glClear(gl_flags);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, if you comment out the vec4_from_rgba and clear_color assignment and replace it with a manual value assignment such as clear_color = vec4(1.0); (or clear_color.x = 1.0f , ...y=1.0f etc) Do you get full white background?

Comment: @Tagger5926 Yes

Comment: What happens when you set all values to 0? Is there a specific color that you want transparent?

Comment: @Tagger5926, set all values to 0 will get a full black background. I just want to set a transparent background, and draw other image on it.

Comment: Looks like rgb is working fine but the w component is not. If w component is equivalent to the alpha channel and it is a value ranging from 0 to 1 then it really shouldn't matter what RGB value you set if clear_color is 0.0f. It should be fully transparent. So you are saying, setting it to 0.5f has no effect on the color transparency?

Comment: If so, could you try not using the other flags. i.e. gs_clear( GS_CLEAR_COLOR, &clear_color, 0, 0 ); or gs_clear( CLEAR_COLOR | CLEAR_DEPTH | CLEAR_STENCIL,&clear_color, 0, 0 );

Comment: @Tagger5926, i try both gs_clear( GS_CLEAR_COLOR, &clear_color, 0, 0 ) and gs_clear( CLEAR_COLOR | CLEAR_DEPTH | CLEAR_STENCIL,&clear_color, 0, 0 ), but i get a full black background again

Comment: "obs's code set the alpha to 1.0 ,I try to set the others value like 0.5f, but it is not working" SO what do you expect to happen when you change the alpha value of the clear color? Implementing transparency requires a lot more than just setting some alpha values, you have to also enable/use blending, set the correct modes, think about drawing order, and also potentially about composition with transparency.